# Is the XAP file from Visual Studio 2010 a valid App?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The .xap that has been generated in Visual Studio 2010(Windows SDK 7.8) seems to have the one mentioned in the wiki (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211475.aspx) which is for Visual Studio 2012.

If I submit the app will Microsoft process the xap or not ?

Comment: Why not try and find out?

Comment: @Will It works yay !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build that xap file using the Release build and if you correctly fill all info, your app can be submitted to the store.

Comment: There's an AppManifest file(the file generated by VS 2010  http://paste.ubuntu.com/8308915/) in that, should it have the template specified in  here or the default one (which is very different) there is also an WMAppManifest.xml(http://pastebin.com/0pzEqnQs) file which seems to have other info